# Formatting a Number in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have following method in Javascript for formatting a number and get output as - $250.00

```
formatNumber(Math.round((finalTotal - parseFloat(SellerAmtNoFormat)) * 100) / 100, "$###,###,###,##0.00");
```

Can anyone please suggest the equivalent in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formatNumber(Math.round((finalTotal - parseFloat(SellerAmtNoFormat)) * 100) / 100, "$###,###,###,##0.00");
```

There!

Comment: ..dont forget the radix param on parseFloat!

Answer (score 3):

JQuery consists entirely of javascript.  So you example line above will work exactly the same in jQuery.

If there was a problem with the above code, what was the exact problem?

Comment: its not working fine. Its breaking down , showing error :Object expected though all the Values are correct

Comment: @Basavaraj The question isn't how to do this in jQuery - the question is how to write JavaScript that works. Try asking a different question, making it clear that you are getting a JavaScript error with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [jQuery NumberFormatter plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter).